# Convert any audio to mp3 format using python

Tags: javascript, python, django, audio, mp3

I am working on a python django project where i am using twillio to send voice messages to the users. I allowed users to upload mp3 format files to send it to other users. But now i want to allow users to upload any audio format file to send others, but my problem is that twillio only allows mp3 format for voice. So i am looking for any package which converts the uploaded file to audio file on django backend. 
Please suggest me some package or some way to accomplish this. I searched for the package or hints over the internet but found nothing. Provide me some packages link or any docs to do it.

Help will be appriciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about django, however , in plain `python` world, if you want to convert any format to mp3 , `pydub`  has quick and easy way.

It can be installed using `pip install pydub`
Supported formats are `ogg, flv, mp4, wma, acc, wav, mp3` and documentation on `pydub` [can be found here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

Here is a demo code that converts from `wav` to `mp3` or `raw` to `mp3`. Other formats are pretty similar as listed in documentation.

**Demo Code:**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# wave and raw don’t use ffmpeg
wav_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav", format="wav")
raw_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav", format="raw",
                                   frame_rate=44100, channels=2, sample_width=2)

wav_audio.export("audio.mp3", format="mp3")
raw_audio.export("audio1.mp3", format="mp3")
```